# Drag Drop not working over swiper-slide

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Implementing a drag drop on my app but it is not working. Do not know what i am doing wrong. Showing my html code.

```
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
<!-- Additional required wrapper -->
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->

    <li class="swiper-slide">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
            <img id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('images/front/clicktoplay.jpg')}}" alt="First slide">
        </button>
        <a href="#" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event);" >Drag Me</a> // aLso tried on link but not working
        <div class="close">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
```

Here is simply call a function

```
 function drag(ev) {
    console.log('dragstart');
 }
```

Missing something.??

Comment: What are you using?  Title says [`swiper-slide`](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/)?  Tag says [`jquery-ui-draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)?  Code says `ondragstart="drag(event);"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function, rather than giving a reference to it. Use this

```
<a href="#" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag" >Drag Me</a> // aLso tried on link but not working
```